# 757: unexpected token at '<!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, open-uri

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

@result = JSON.parse(open(URI.parse(url)).read)

757: unexpected token at '<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang='en'> <head><script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ||[];NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()]);</script> <title>Fundly | Search </title> <meta charset='utf-8'> <meta content='initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width' name='viewport'> <script src="//cdn.optimizely.com/js/3536001.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" /> <meta content="V3GRiKIwWG9+WxN7VsiNtqOnkWu1CkuutIqJ00CQLrQ=" name="csrf-token" /> <meta name='description'> <meta content='noindex' name='robots'> <!-- Facebook OpenGraph metadata --> <meta content='Search' property='og:title'> <meta content='website' property='og:type'> <meta content='https://fundly.com/search' property='og:url'> <meta content='http://fundly.com/assets/logos/v2/fundly_logo_vertical_lockup.png' property='og:image'> <meta content='Fundly' property='og:site_name'> <meta content='Start Your Search' property='og:description'> <meta content='148669528535835' property='fb:app_id'> <!-- End Facebook OpenGraph metadata --> <link href="//doapv6pcsx1wa.cloudfront.net/assets/favicon_heart-ac3d0cee1ff7eb05cfec822b455dc319.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" /> <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?
```

Comment: You are trying to parse HTML as JSON. Is there a JSON data source at the URI you are calling?